# Custom listview search works successfully but doesnt show new results on pressing backspace in the edittext

Tags: java, android

I am using a custom adapter for a listview .It has a search bar in it.

The code :

```
txtsearcher.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                StoreDetails.this.cdadp.getFilter().filter(s.toString());               
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

The adapter class:

```
public CustomDetailsAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<Store_data> store_list,double current_latitude,double current_longitude)
    {
        this.context=context;
        details_inflate=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.store_list=store_list;
        this.current_latitude=current_latitude;
        this.current_longitude=current_longitude;
         temp_list=store_list;


    }
public class filter_here extends Filter{
        //ArrayList<String> Names=new ArrayList<String>(); 
        //ArrayList<Store_data> store_list;
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             //store_list=new ArrayList<Store_data>();
//          for(int i=0;i<store_list.size();i++)
//          {
//              store_names.add(store_list.get(i).store_name);
//          }
            FilterResults Result = new FilterResults();
            // if constraint is empty return the original names
            if(constraint.length() == 0 ){
                Result.values = temp_list;
                Result.count = temp_list.size();

            }
            else if(constraint.length()>0)
            {
            ArrayList<Store_data> Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<Store_data>();
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();


            for(Store_data s:store_list){
                String filterableString=s.store_name.toLowerCase().toString();
                if(filterableString.contains(filterString)){
                    Filtered_Names.add(s);
                }

            }
            Result.values = Filtered_Names;
            Result.count = Filtered_Names.size();


            }
            return Result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(results.count==0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else
            {
            store_list = (ArrayList<Store_data>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

    }
```

The search works fine.But when i type "SP" all values containing SP are shown.When i press Space bar after that entries with "SP" and other words are shown.But when i press backspace on the keypad and make the string as "S" ,all values containing S are not shown.How do i register the back pressed event.

I tried the following, but it doesnt work:

```
txtsearcher.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                {
                    String s=txtsearcher.getText().toString();
                    StoreDetails.this.cdadp.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try to move this line StoreDetails.this.cdadp.getFilter().filter(s.toString()); on afterTextChanged().

Comment: Tried that but didnt make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are listening to the back key (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) but you say "backspace in edit text". Do you mean the delete key on the keyboard? Try KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL in this case